# Bootstrap highlight empty input/field in form

Tags: html, forms, input, bootstrap-5, highlight

I have an "Update Profile" form. I would like to highlight empty inputs which are not required but "nice to have" for users to fill in.

Is it possible to highlight them if the input fields are empty (some sort of glow similar to the active field below or some other highlighting method)?

See example here:

[image: Glow when active input field]

```css
.form-control:focus {
   border-color: #FF0000;
   
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example">

    <!-- Example Code -->
    
    <div class="input-group mb-3" bis_skin_checked="1">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">Default</span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default">
    </div>
    
    
    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your focus color is overruled by Bootstrap. However if you add `!important` then the input will have a red border on focus. See: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/jOvwvwR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make those inputs `required`.

```css
input:not(:valid) {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
First Name <input type="text" required><br>
Last Name <input type="text" required>
```

You can do it with Javascript and then you do not need to make them required:

```js
addEventListener("load", function() {
    let preferredElements = document.getElementsByClassName("preferred");
    for (let preferred of preferredElements) {
         preferred.addEventListener("input", function() {
             preferred.classList[preferred.value ? "remove" : "add"]("highlighted");
         });
         preferred.classList[preferred.value ? "remove" : "add"]("highlighted");
    }
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input name="a" class="preferred" type="text"><br>
<input name="b" class="preferred" type="text">
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I don't want to make them required. I am looking to detect if box is empty and then hint it can be filled. 
Some users may not have the data to fill these fields and the app should still run. However, if they have the data, the app can do more stuff.

Comment: @user3507584 provided an answer that solves your problem, even though I used Javascript to implement it.